# magento: PayPal NVP gateway errors: Timeout processing request (#10001: Internal Error)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am getting a strange error, which I cannot seem to track down on the Paypal error list:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/

This is specific to Magento Paypal checkout, and the error log says:

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'PayPal NVP gateway errors: Timeout processing request (#10001: Internal Error). Correlation ID: c93a329880ec. Version: .' in /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php:579
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/magento/app/code/community/Paypal/Expresscheckout/Model/Api/Nvp.php(1042): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'PayPal NVP gate...')
#1 /var/www/magento/app/code/community/Paypal/Expresscheckout/Model/Api/Nvp.php(1003): Paypal_Expresscheckout_Model_Api_Nvp->_handleCallErrors(Array)
#2 /var/www/magento/app/code/community/Paypal/Expresscheckout/Model/Api/Nvp.php(612): Paypal_Expresscheckout_Model_Api_Nvp->call('SetExpressCheck...', Array)
#3 /var/www/magento/app/code/community/Paypal/Expresscheckout/Model/Express/Checkout.php(351): Paypal_Expresscheckout_Model_Api_Nvp->callSetExpressCheckout()
#4 /var/www/magento/app/code/community/Paypal/Expresscheckout/Controller/Express/Abstract.php(127): Paypal_Expresscheckout_Model_Express_Checkout->start('https://order...', 'https://order...')
#5 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Paypal_Expresscheckout_Controller_Express_Abstract->startAction()
#6 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('start')
#7 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /var/www/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('default', 'store')
#11 {main}
```

I could not see why it should time out after 3 seconds of processing, and when I have tested with the sanbox mode, it went through without any issues, yet with the real test it fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you testing from localhost?

Comment: no, I am testing on the actual site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been related to the security credentials between Payapal Checkin and Paypal Express Checkout not being set correctly.

The error is not appearing anymore after fiddling with the security credentials, and turning sandbox mode off.

Hope this helps someone some day.

Comment: But how to make it working in sandbox mode? I need to test some orders in Sandbox mode before switching into Live.